# How to accept a list based on 4 cells of double in dart?

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

I have the following object:

```
const coordinates = {
  'one': [10, 15, 30, 40],
  'two': [60, 85, 100, 120],
  ...
}
```

As you can see, `coordinates` is a map that has a key of `String` and a value of a list that is based on 4 cells of double.

I could tell Dart that `coordinates` is a type of :

```
Map<String, List<double>> coordinates = {...}
```

But Dart won't enforce that each list in the map will have 4 cells? I'm assuming it can be achieved by doing `assert`, but I'm not sure how the syntax works inside map.

Comment: If you want to use an assert you must loop through all the map values, ie: `assert(map.values.every((e) => e.length == 4));`, but there is really no reason to do so instead of creating a class that will accept only 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a list is not part of a type in Dart and there are therefore no way to enforce the number of items in a list by using types. Instead I recommend you make a class which contains the four values which can then ensure the number of elements are correct. It will also improve the readability of your code since you make it easier to understand the reason for the four values.

Comment: There's a way of doing so using assertions AFAIK

Comment: Note that assertions are not enabled in production mode: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert